# Unable to deploy to LocomotiveCMS Rails Engine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, imagemagick, rails-engines, locomotivecms

I have been following the [basic setup for the LocomotiveCMS](http://doc.locomotivecms.com/making-blog/1-3-deploy-to-engine) on how to deploy to a Rails engine, but still I get an error when executing `bundle exec wagon push development`:

```
* Pushing Site
* Pushing Snippets
  en
    updating Footer.............................................................[done]
* Pushing ContentTypes
* Pushing Pages
  en
    updating index      error => Command failed ('/usr/local/bin/identify' '-ping' '-format' '%m %w %h' '/webDev/locomotiveCMS/loc_cms/tmp/uploads/1401627123-3224-3727/favicon.png') with exit status  and stderr dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/lib/liblzma.5.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/bin/identify
  Reason: image not found
```

One possible issue that I found through another post was regarding Imagemagick. But even a reinstall with homebrew didn't change anything.

I am running OSX 10.7.5 if that makes a difference?

Comment: looks like it is referring to `favicon.png` at `/webDev...` I suspect that you don't have this folder at root level.

Comment: I changed the path for the post...it has the right path in the original version.